# Programmatically remove paired bluetooth devices in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

Is there a way to programmatically remove paired Bluetooth devices from iOS device settings?

Right now we only know that there are some devices saved in Bluetooth device settings, and we ask the user to remove them manually, but we need to make sure there isn't another way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This is not possible. There is no access to BR/EDR connections at all. BLE pairing will automatically remove themselves from Settings when the device disconnects. You can cancel the connection, but you can't force it to disconnect.

You can tell the difference between these by the (i) beside the "Not Connected" row. If there is an (i), it is a BR/EDR pairing and the user must manually forget the device. If there is no (i), it is a BLE connection, then the device can only be removed by the connection being dropped by the OS (which generally happens shortly after all apps drop their connections).

Note that it is possible to have both kinds of connections at the same time. They are completely independent of each other.